# Accessing a JSON property with SwitfyJSON returns an empty string

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to print a property from a JSON using SwiftyJSON on XCode (obviously with Swift language)

My first line prints well, but the second one prints nothing, I have checked the output of the first println() in an online parser and the striing is consistent:

```
var jdata = JSON(self.serverResponse)
println("jdata RAW: "+jdata.stringValue)
println("jdata.responseData: "+jdata["responseData"].stringValue)
```

This is the result of printing both things, as you can see the 2nd one is just blank:

```
jdata RAW: 
{
    "responseData": {
        "emotion":"",
        "lastinput":"What is your favourite color",
        "answer":"My favourite color is orange. What is yours?",
        "link": {
            "href":"",
            "target":""
        },
        "extraData": {
            "action":{"name":"displayClickableList","values":[{"label":"green","key":"1"},{"label":"yellow","key":"2"},{"label":"red","key":"3"}]},"type":"list"
        },
        "responseSession": {
            "id":"1ebfcd96c3c1f206dfb4087bc553",
            "transaction":"2"
        },
        "responseDetails": null,
        "responseStatus": 200,
        "applicationUrl": "http://moto-dev.cloud.com:88/moto-va-1/;jsessionid=1ebfc206dfb4087bc553"
    }
}


jdata.responseData:
```

I am new to Swift, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your property seems to be a dictionary and can't be converted to string value.

But you can simply print it like this:

`println("jdata.responseData: \(jdata["responseData"])")`

Comment: The compiler will not accept that line, are some escape characters missing there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a way to obtain the contents of the nested "action" property. It seems that Swifty cannot print jdata["responseData"] because it is not a string (it is a Dictionary with more stuff inside) and it cannot convert it to a string either.
The approach that worked for me was to access through the different layers of JSONS to the final property that I want, and -then- handle it.
For example:

```
var jdata = JSON(data: data!)
var jaction=jdata["responseData"]["extraData"]["action"]
println("jaction")
println(jaction.stringValue)
```

Will return this:

```
jaction
%7B%22name%22%3A%22displayClickableList%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%7B%22label%22%3A%22green%22%2C%22key%22%3A%221%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22yellow%22%2C%22key%22%3A%222%22%7D%2C%7B%22label%22%3A%22red%22%2C%22key%22%3A%223%22%7D%5D%7D
```

And only then, since there is no more JSON Nesting going on, I can take that strange string and URLdecode it.
Printing something like (or anything in between):

```
println(jaction=jdata["responseData"].stringValue) //returns nothing!
println(jaction=jdata["responseData"]["extraData"].stringValue) //returns nothing!
```

Will return nothing, because the contents are a Dictionary, not a string.
It is not an intuitive behavior, I had to spend the entire morning struggling to understand the way it works, in Android I do this in another way.